# Why would a Python call to an sqllite3 database crash with only 'Killed' as an output

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to run some 3rd party code that attempts to read a database it has created. However, when I run this code, it crashes and only gives me the word `Killed` as output.

I inserted

```
import pdb
pdb_set_trace()
```

Before the relevant section of the code:

```
db_name = mod_path / 'data/ais.db'
with sqlite3.connect(str(db_name)) as conn:
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master "+
              "WHERE type='table' AND name='meta'")
```

Which produced this output:

```
> /media/me/Fortress/bb/src/bb/data.py(316)download_data()
-> db_name = mod_path / 'data/ais.db'
(Pdb) n
> /media/me/Fortress/bb/src/bb/data.py(317)download_data()
-> with sqlite3.connect(str(db_name)) as conn:
(Pdb) n
> /media/me/Fortress/bb/src/bb/data.py(318)download_data()
-> c = conn.cursor()
(Pdb) conn
<sqlite3.Connection object at 0x7fa2f1e9d840>
(Pdb) n
> /media/me/Fortress/bb/src/bb/data.py(319)download_data()
-> c.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master "+
(Pdb) c
Killed
```

So, I know the issue is with the `SELECT` stmt, but I don't know much about datbases, so don't know what the next debugging step I should take is. Is there a problem I should check for in the database? Or something wrong with the `SELECT` stmt? Or something else entirely?

Comment: How many results do you expect from that SELECT statement?  A few?  Dozens?  Hundreds?  Millions?

Comment: I ask because it sounds like the OS killed the process because it was using too much memory.

Comment: @JohnGordon - I don't know, but the entire db is only 20.5kB, so it can't be too big..... Can it?